# MVC Default route with nullable id not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

A simple routing scenario is not working for me.

my route registration looks like this

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Users_default",
                "Users/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id= UrlParameter.Optional });
```

and i am expecting it to honor the requests for

```
users/profile/
users/profile/1
users/profile/2
```

with the following controller

```
 public class ProfileController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(int? id)
        {
            var user = id == null ? (UserModel)HttpContext.Session["CurrentUser"] : userManager.GetUserById((int)id);
            return View(user);
        }
    }
```

it works for `users/profile` but not for `users/profile/1`
i've tried few different things but i know the answer must be simple, its just my lack of knowledge, what am i missing here.

Comment: `users/profile/1` means its trying to find a method named `1` on `ProfileController`

Comment: how do i overcome that? i need to pass the route id to index.

Comment: Make it `users/profile/Index/1` (or add a more specific route if you don't want `Index` to appear in the url

Comment: thanks Stephen could you please elaborate on how to add a more specific route in this scenario

Comment: `"Users/Profile/{id}", new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index", id= UrlParameter.Optional });`

Comment: @StephenMuecke You've been very helpful, thanks. works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i dont want index to appear. i want to use the same method for both users/profile/1 and users/profile/

Then don't put action into your URL.

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Users_default",
    "Users/{controller}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id= UrlParameter.Optional });
```

The route you have defined will not allow index to be optional because it is followed by another parameter (in this case "id"). Only the last parameter can be optional on all but the default route.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your route interprets as:
 `{controller: "profile", action: "1"}`.

You need to point you details action url explicit, something like this:
`users/profile/index/1`

Comment: i dont want index to appear. i want to use the same method for both users/profile/1 and users/profile/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Attribute routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx#enabling-attribute-routing)

The code would look like

```
public class ProfileController : Controller
{
    [Route("users/profile/{id}")]
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        var user = id == null ? (UserModel)HttpContext.Session["CurrentUser"] : userManager.GetUserById((int)id);

        return View();
    }
}
```

And you have to modify your RouteConfig

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // This will enable attribute routing in your project
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

So now you can use users/profile for your default behaviour and users/profile/ for a specific profile.